# iTunesConnect "We can't process your request." when going to "App-Specific Shared Secret"

Tags: ios

Whenever i try to navigate to App-Specific Shared Secret within ItunesConnect the dialog box attempts to load briefly then I get directed to a crash page titled 
"We can't process your request".

I've reset safari clearing all website data and also used other computers.

I've contacted Apple who are sending an email shortly requesting more information but wondered if anyone else had come across a similar fault?

Comment: Previously I couldn't login and saw the same dialog box. I did nothing and I thought that it's apple bug. I just tried to login 5-7 times and system let me go into.

Comment: same problem here

Comment: @NadavB I’ve added my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The problem was due to not previously having created a master shared secret.

Once I did this then I could generate the shared secret for the specific application.

Answer (score 8):

Another very easy solution which worked for me:

**Use safari**

Comment: Inconvenience me by blocking access to your site on Chrome just to get me to use Safari for 5 minutes. Was it really worth it?

Comment: Haha, it helped

Comment: What about other platforms? Not supported?

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar issue, when I was getting invited to join Apple Developer Program. I tried joining through the invitation link and I would always get the "We can't process your request" message.

The solution was to:

- Log in to an iPhone/iPad with that particular Apple id.
- Try to install an app.
- You will get a terms and condition pop up that you should accept.
- Install the app
- Wait for a while until Apple fast servers update your status (around 1 hour for me)
- Now you should be able to proceed without the weird message.

Answer (score -1):

I think need to update Mac OS to latest will solve problem. Alternatively you can use google chrome browser.